# Setting Up A Website App On The Shared Network

Tags: asp.net

How do I setup the project on the network instead of localhost? I want to setup a Remote Site, I think is the lingo

- Go into visual studio
- File, open website and put the website name in the box and a password to open the source.
- Create a unique url name like myWebApp.mycompany.com

When I create a new website application in visual studio. When I am ready to debug Visual Studio sets all this up for me and it runs on local host automatically.

I guess in my scenario I gotta set it up manually. How do I accomplish this?

I created a new virtual directory, went through the permissions wizard and keep getting this error:

```
Failed to access IIS metabase.
```

Comment: If you use Web Application Projects, then you don't need to worry about the source getting out.

Comment: How do I setup the project on the network instead of localhost?

Comment: you don't. You create the project on your local system (using source control, if  possible), then you publish it to the shared location where it will be hosted.

Comment: @John ok you have a handy tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to deploy somewhere you can access via a windows share, it is often easier to just deploy to disk by publishing to the file system and setup the IIS bits manually. In that case, you'll need the name of the server and a share to push to.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the url will be configured in IIS where you host the web app.  When you are debugging in visual studio it is running a copy of the web app locally so you can test it.  You shouldn't be trying to host the web app within the visual studio debugger.

To configure this you will need to set the host header for the website to myWebApp.mycompany.com.  This will tell IIS that incoming requests with this domain map to this website.